# messed up model rig in blender

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, rigidbody

everytime I download Model from Sketchfab animated , the Rig Is all over the place its very messy , I  think it happens only in blender I wonder and it would be very helpful to see how to fix this issue
this is the animation rig https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/animated-eagle-de73b663acbc426e8e6c107fd25e08cd
[image]

my blend file [image]

Comment: Switch the armature to Edit mode, in the Transform Pivot Point panel switch to Individual Origins, select all the bones and scale down. If no bones are parented to each other it should work

Comment: it worked thanks brother

Comment: it worked just fine , now I am trying to rig and animate the eagle , but the problem I am facing for hours is that the eagle is already animated , but its going up and down I tried to switch on every bone to see what is causing it but  I cant stop it from jumping , If you can help i would really appreciate , I am trying to finish a project today , thanks in advance

Comment: Your armature is parented to an empty, select it and Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformation

Comment: sorry for the late reply moonboots, I went to the empty and tried alt p clear and keep transformation but the eagle is still going up and down ( not the wings and others) just like seems its jumping , sorry I might did something wrong but i did what exactly u said i reckon and there was 2 empties

Comment: ok it worked mate i just wanted it to stop the moving down and up and i deleted the animation on the bip01, thanks for your help

Comment: If you unparent the bird armature it should not follow anymore, but yes, if you need to keep the parentage, you need to close the action of the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the armature to *Edit* mode, in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel switch to *Individual Origins*, select all the bones and scale down. If no bones are parented to each other it should work